# I can't play Reus on Steam

Tags: steam, reus

It's the Steam Summer Sale and I bought a game called Reus. I downloaded it clicked play and then it asked for the administrator password, I put it in and then my Steam crashed. Why did this happen?

Comment: Does it happen to other games?

Comment: Is this on a shared computer?

Comment: No, this is my computer, but my dad is administrator. @deutschZuid yes, it does happen with some other games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what you have said in your comments, I think the best course of action would be to ask your dad to log on to the computer under his account, log in to your Steam account, then run the games you are having the issues with crashing on. If he can get on them fine, switch back to your account and try again. My reasoning is that you not having administrative privileges is probably the culprit and him being the one to get the first runs and installs completed will solve your problem.

If this does not help, I suggest uninstalling the games which crash and then downloading/installing/running them for the first time on your father's account.

Comment: I tried the games on my account after I de-downloaded it from mine and then downloading it on my dad's account, but no luck. Should I try to play them on my dad's?

Comment: It's worth a shot.

Comment: I did everything that you told, but my cp just can't play it because it need this 3D graphics thing that I don't have. Thanks for the help.